# Understanding optocoupler's operation through simulation

Tags: ltspice, simulation, opto-isolator, optoelectronics

I am trying to understand how an optocoupler (4N25) works by looking at the datasheet and simulating a test circuit in LTSpice, but I am having some issues.

To begin with, for the sake of trying to match the testing conditions for the current transfer ratio (CTR) shown in the 4N25's [datasheet](https://www.vishay.com/docs/83725/4n25.pdf), I built a circuit with a current through the optocoupler's diode of \$I_f = 10 \ mA\$ and a collector-emitter voltage of \$V_{CE} \simeq 10 \ V\$. The circuit is shown in the figure below.
[image]

Then, I measured the current through R1 to be around \$I_{R1} = 7 \ mA\$ and I became confused, since I can't understand how this value can match what is written in the datasheet.

In fact, under the specified testing conditions (and assuming a temperature \$T = 25 °C\$), the typical CTR value should be 50%, therefore I would expect approximately \$I_{R1} = 5 \ mA\$. At the same time, however, according to Fig. 6 (Collector Emitter Current vs.
Temperature and LED Current) in the datasheet, my \$I_f = 10 \ mA\$ should correspond to a collector current, equal to the current through \$R_1\$, of about \$8 \ mA\$, which seems closer to what I measure in LTSpice, but also different from the current that the typical CTR would imply.

Therefore, I would like to ask:

- how should I interpret my simulation results?
- why do the curves shown in Fig. 6 appear not to follow the typical CTR value?

Answer (score 2):

The datasheet simply says CTR is 20% minimum and 50% typical. And that is at If=10mA.

Datasheet does not say what is the maximum CTR.

So if simulator result shows 70% CTR, it is within specification, since it is more than 20%.

I don'y see Figure 6 contradicting with this. Figure shows typical results and they are more than 20% and around 50%. It simply shows Ic versus If, and the datasheet CTRs are defined at 10mA If and 10V Vce.

Comment: Thank you, I edited my post because "contradictory" was not the right word to use. What I am still not being able to understand, however, is why the value for \$I_{CE}\$ shown in the curves in Fig. 6 differs significantly from the value which would be obtained by applying the typical CTR: in my case, I would have expected \$I_{CE} = 5 \ mA\$ @ \$I_f = 10 \ mA\$, since it should be \$\mathrm{CTR} = 0.5\$

Comment: @gwn In general, the curve shifts around (vertically or horizontally) depending on base CTR and other parameter variations. These are *very imprecise* devices; the simulation is well within expectations.

Comment: @gwn Optocouplers are very difficult to manufacture with tight tolerances on CTR, and the CTR degrades over time. Most optocouplers that specify both a minimum and a maximum CTR have at least a 2:1 ratio between max and min, and most of *those* are at least 5:1. You can't get precise analog transfer across an isolation barrier with an optocoupler without some additional form of feedback.

Answer (score 2):

Let's run a sim...

[image]

CTR looks very different from the datasheet (non saturated case):

[image]

Here's the model from LTSpice

```
* Copyright © Linear Technology Corp. 1998, 1999, 2000.  All rights reserved.
*
.subckt 4N25 1 2 3 4 5
R1 N003 2 2
D1 1 N003 LD
G1 3 5 N003 2 .876m
C1 1 2 18p
Q1 3 5 4 [4] NP
.model LD D(Is=1e-20 Cjo=18p)
.model NP NPN(Bf=610 Vaf=140 Ikf=15m Rc=1 Cjc=19p Cje=7p Cjs=7p C2=1e-15)
.ends 4N25
```

So it models the LED, with a small series resistance, and the output transistor... The base of said transistor being driven by a voltage dependent current source whose input is on the series resistance.

In other words, it's plotting the hFe vs Ib of the output transistor, not the optocoupler CTR, which is not modelled.

A quick check confirms...

[image]

> how should I interpret my simulation results?

The model is too crude.